# Почему ответ от бота приходит несколько раз

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, бот

Пытаюсь написать чат-бота,

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
        return;
    }
    $i=0;
    $confirmationToken = '******';
    $token = '***************************************************************';
    $secretKey = '*********';
    //Получаем и декодируем уведомление
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    //Проверяем, что находится в поле "type"
    switch ($data->type) {
    //Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса...
        case 'confirmation':
        //...отправляем строку для подтверждения
            echo $confirmation_token;
            break;

        //Если это уведомление о новом сообщении...
        case 'message_new':
        //...получаем id его автора
            $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
            //затем с помощью users.get получаем данные об авторе
            $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token={$token}&v=5.0"));

            //и извлекаем из ответа его имя
            $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;

            //С помощью messages.send отправляем ответное сообщение

            $request_params = array(
            'message' => "Твоё последнее сообщение, {$data->object->body}!",
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.0'
            );

            $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

            file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);

            //Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API

            echo('ok');

            break;

    }
    ?>
```

И он отвечает на отправленное сообщение, но по какой-то причине отвечает по несколько раз и при этом ответ может содержать значение которое я ему ни когда не отправлял или отправлял раньше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое может происходить и как это исправить?

Comment: Это может происходить, если ранее Вы тестировали бота и Ваш сервер не возвращал правильный ответ. Дело в том, что ВК некоторое время хранит запросы и ответы на них. Если произошла какая-то ошибка, то ВК попытается отправить запросы снова, но позже, пока не добьётся верного ответа.